# why have JUnit MethodRule and TestWatchman have been deprecated?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

org.junit.rules.MethodRule and org.junit.rules.TestWatchman have been deprecated.

one interesting note was at: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/519 , in part:
"Many developers are legitimate reasons to stick with MethodRule and the JUnit team has no plans to remove support for MethodRule..."

http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestWatchman.html documents:
"Deprecated. MethodRule is deprecated. Use TestWatcher implements TestRule instead." and provides some example code.

What is the reasoning behind marking these deprecated? 
What is the tradeoff between TestWatcher and the deprecated TestWachman?
Do you have a good link for a synopsis or overview on this specific topic?

Comment: According to the release notes for version 4.11 of JUnit: "MethodRule is no longer deprecated." See https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.11.md

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason is simple, `TestRule` was planned to replace `MethodRule`. `MethodRule` was introduced implemented in 4.7, and it is an interface with one method:

```
Statement apply(Statement base, FrameworkMethod method, Object target)
```

`FrameworkMethod` is (almost) an internal JUnit class, which shouldn't have been exposed in the first place. `object` is the object on which the method will be run, so for example, you can modify state of the test using reflection.

`TestRule` was introduced in 4.9, however, is:

```
Statement apply(Statement base, Description description)
```

`Description` is a immutable POJO containing the description of the test. The way to modify state within a test is to encapsulate correctly within the test using a `TestRule`. It's an altogether cleaner design.

The specific difference between `TestWatchman(MethodRule)` and `TestWatcher(TestRule)` is minimal, except that TestWatcher has better error handling, so this should be used in preference. Both have overridable methods such as `succeeded()`, `failed()`, `starting()`, `finished()`.

```
public static class WatchmanTest {
   private static String watchedLog;

   @Rule
   public TestWatcher watchman= new TestWatcher() {
     @Override
     protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
       watchedLog+= description + "\n";
     }

     @Override
     protected void succeeded(Description description) {
       watchedLog+= description + " " + "success!\n";
     }
   };

   @Test
   public void fails() {
     fail();
   }

   @Test
   public void succeeds() {
   }
}
```

`TestWatcher(TestRule)` handles exceptions in the overidden methods. If exceptions are thrown, then the test method fails after execution of the test, rather than during.

For more information, see [TestWatcher](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.java) and [TestWatchman](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/MethodRule.java)

Comment: so why MethodRule is not deprecated anymore in JUnit 4.11 ?

Comment: It was de-deprecated because it still has some use cases: see https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/519